# iptables: Packets about generated locally and heading to local

Tags: iptables

Does packet which is generated locally and heading to local take PREROUTING chain?

I added some rules to iptables to forward http request for my public IP to locally binded Nginx.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp3s0f0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o lo -p tcp --sport 80 -j SNAT --to-source xxx.yyy.zzz.www
```

and also set policy of filter tables FORWARD chain to ACCEPT.

As a result, these rules worked and I can access to Nginx in another machine, but I can't access to xxx.yyy.zzz.www in the machine which has xxx.yyy.zzz.www IP. (with Curl and Chrome)

Why can't I access to Nginx in the xxx.yyy.zzz.www machine?

Comment: Look at logs, for example (on Ubuntu): `cat /var/log/syslog | grep enp3s0f0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, the locally originated packets don't pass the PREROUTING chains (see this [wiki diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) - the path of local packets starts at the local process block). Also, these packets pass only the INPUT/OUTPUT chains and never the FORWARD.

To redirect the local originated packets you should insert the DNAT/REDIRECT rule into the nat/OUTPUT chain:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dst xxx.yyy.zzz.www --dport 80 \
  -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I got it.

Thank you so much for your answer. :)